# Sidebar should slide out in same motion as slide in

Tags: jquery, css

CSS

```
#overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.sidePanelOpen #overlay{
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    z-index: 9000;
}

.sidebar-panel{
    width: 440px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:-100%;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 35px;
    z-index: 9100;
    overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
     -moz-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
       -o-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
          transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000); /* easeOutExpo */
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
     -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
       -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000); /* easeOutExpo
}
.sidePanelOpen .sidebar-panel{
    right:0;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.icon-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('body').addClass('sidePanelOpen');

});
$('#overlay').on('click', function() {
    $('body').removeClass('sidePanelOpen');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar-panel">
  <div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #eee;">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/9/)

The issue is:
1. when click icon, the sidebar will slide in slow - correct as in transition
2. when close overlay, the sidebar slides out too fast - which is not correct.

The sidebar should slide in and out in same motion (see transition css above). I tried to add transition to .sidePanelOpen .sidebar-panel{} but on click overlay, the sidebar still slide out too fast.

How to make sidebar slide in and out in same motion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually they're the same but you can't notice it because easeOutExpo gives a fast start and slow end. Use easeInOutExpo instead with the array of:

```
cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/15/) to go the updated fiddle. All you should do now is to set the timing as you pleease.

Comment: oh! so i have to tweak time delay. Many thanks for help

Comment: I tested it and it works well. What version of FF do you use?

Comment: FF version 30.0. more like it opens and close not sliding smoothly

Comment: I've tested it on several devices and it really works well. It's awkward.